# Odds of distribution happening under uniform RV.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have 10 balls thrown into three urns $A$, $B$, $C$. There are 7 balls in $A$, 2 in $B$, 1 in $C$.

What are the odds happening if the distribution of tosses over urns was uniform?

#### My approach:

Ways of grouping like this are $N_1 = 10C7 * 3C2 * 1C1$. Since we don't care about the order (which group is which), this becomes $N_2 = N_1/3$. (And since uniform, all grouping outcomes are equally weighted).

Secondly, we need to know in how many ways we can potentially split the 10 balls into up to 3 groups. That should be $N_3=3^{10}$ (since every single ball could go into three different ways.

Now, since I apparently cared about the order when calculating $N_3$, I believe the answer should be $N_1/N_3$. Is that correct? Is there a neater approach?

Answer (score 1):

Close; you we on the right approach, but missed the runway by just a *wee* bit.

If we didn't care about the order of the grouping, we would *multiply* $N_1$ by $3!$ to obtain the ways to sort the balls into groups of size 7,2,1 *and arrange* those groups.

However, we actually *do* care about the order of the grouping; because the urns are *labelled* and the favoured event is that specific counts are in specific urns.

So the probability of this is just $N_1/N_3$

$$\dfrac{\dbinom {10}7 \dbinom 3 2\dbinom 1 1}{3^{10}}~=~\dfrac{10!}{7!~2!~3^{10}}$$

Comment: What would be the answer if I actually did not label the urns, but was merely interested in the combination 7-2-1?

Comment: @FooBar .... multiply by $3!$

Comment: This issue doesn't let me sleep - sorry for digging up this question. Take as alternative example `[3, 2, 1, 1, 1]`. Then, $N_1 = 3360$, $N_2 = 5^8= 390625$. $N_1/N_2 = 0.0086016$. Multiplying that with $5!$ yields $1.032192$ - too large to be a rounding error. Why is it larger than one?

Comment: @FooBar, because three of the urns have identical amounts of balls, changing the order of these urns(among themselves) has no effect.  There are $5!/3!$ distinct ways to arrange the urns with these amounts of balls.  The probability of this pattern occurring in any order is: $$\dfrac{8!}{3!~2!~1!^3}\cdot\dfrac{5!}{3!}\cdot\dfrac{1}{5^8}~=~0.172032$$

Comment: Just to be sure I understood the principle and not the example: The denominator is $3! \cdot 1! \cdot 1!$ - if the group was `[2, 2, 1, 1, 1]` the total number of permutations was $5! / (3! \cdot 2!)$?